# How to get finger positions in Leap Motion using C#

Tags: c#, leap-motion

I want to get finger positions in Leap motion using c#.I'm new to leap motion controller. So i Couldn't find any example code for detecting finger positions, but i tried to come up with some code. I think it has lot of errors.
So, how to get finger positions in Leap Motion using C#?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Leap;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form, ILeapEventDelegate
{


    private Controller controller;
    private LeapEventListener listener;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.controller = new Controller();
        this.listener = new LeapEventListener(this);
        controller.AddListener(listener);
    }


    delegate void LeapEventDelegate(string EventName);
    public void LeapEventNotification(string EventName)
    {
        if (!this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            switch (EventName)
            {
                case "onInit":
                    MessageBox.Show("onInit");
                    break;
                case "onConnect":
                    MessageBox.Show("onConnect");
                    break;
                case "onFrame":
                    MessageBox.Show("onFrame");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
  BeginInvoke(new LeapEventDelegate(LeapEventNotification), new object[] {
  EventName });   
         }
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    }


   public interface ILeapEventDelegate
   {
    void LeapEventNotification(string EventName);
    }

    public class LeapEventListener : Listener
   {
    ILeapEventDelegate eventDelegate;

    public LeapEventListener(ILeapEventDelegate delegateObject)
    {
        this.eventDelegate = delegateObject;
    }
    public override void OnInit(Controller controller)
    {
        this.eventDelegate.LeapEventNotification("onInit");
    }
    public override void OnConnect(Controller controller)
    {
        this.eventDelegate.LeapEventNotification("onConnect");
    }
    public override void OnFrame(Controller controller)
    {
        this.eventDelegate.LeapEventNotification("onFrame");
    }
    public override void OnExit(Controller controller)
    {
        this.eventDelegate.LeapEventNotification("onExit");
    }
    public override void OnDisconnect(Controller controller)
    {
        this.eventDelegate.LeapEventNotification("onDisconnect");
    }
     } 
    }
```

Comment: It would help to show your effort by pasting your code into your question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice  # Mixxiphoid

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it is derived from the [documentation example](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/csharp/devguide/Project_Setup.html). However, you have left out the actual event handlers so nothing will ever happen.

You will see in the linked example that there is a newFrameHandler function. You can change that to access the finger positions in the frame object, which is a snapshot of the tracked hands at a moment in time.

```
    void newFrameHandler(Frame frame)
    {
        foreach(Finger in frame.Fingers){
            Vector fingerPosition = finger.TipPosition;
            //Do something with this information...
        }
    }
```

You can similarly get the hands and then access each hand's fingers, which often is the more natural approach:

```
foreach(Hand hand in frame.Hands){
    foreach(Finger in hand.Fingers){
        Vector fingerPosition = finger.TipPosition;
        //Do something with this information...
    }        
}
```